# How do I show an Open/Save file dialog using an AJAX callback?

Tags: ajax, theming

In the form builder I have the following code.

```
$form['export_to_pdf'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#value' => $this->t('Pdf Format'),
  '#attributes' => array('name'=>'print_pdf',),
  '#ajax'=> array(
    'callback' => '::exportPdf',
    'event' => 'click',
    'effect' => 'fade',
    'prevent' => 'submit',
    'progress' => array(
      'type' => 'throbber',
      'message' => t('Retrieving...'),
    ),
  ),
];
```

The callback function is the following one.

```
public function exportPdf(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) { 
  global $base_url;
  $url = "{$base_url}/pdf_templates/report.pdf";
  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new RedirectCommand($url));
  return $response;
}
```

This works, but it doesn't pop up the Open/Save file dialog. It redirects to the PDF file. How do I make the callback show the Open/Save file dialog so that the users can either open or save according to their wish?

Answer (score 0):

For Open /Save Dialog  pop up you can use following ajax commands in the ajax callback

```
1.OpenModalDialogCommand
2.OpenDialogCommand
```

**Don't forget to include following namespaces**

```
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\OpenModalDialogCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\OpenDialogCommand;

In your ajax callback function add like below:
 $content = AjaxTestController::dialogContents();
 $response = new AjaxResponse();
$title = $this->t('AJAX Dialog & contents');
```

Attach the library necessary for using the Open(Modal)DialogCommand and
     set the attachments for this Ajax response.

$content['#attached']['library'][] = 'core/drupal.dialog.ajax';

```
if you need as modal dialog you can use below statement

$response->addCommand(new OpenModalDialogCommand($title,
$content));
```

or only dialog type

```
 $selector = '#ajax-test-dialog-wrapper-1';
    $response->addCommand(new OpenDialogCommand($selector, $title, $content);
```

return $response;

for any reference you can check below files in the  drupal directory

> core/modules/system/tests/modules/ajax_test/src/form/AjaxTestDialogForm

After completing the dialog command ,you can use  your redirect command to continue

Comment: Is there no way to use the browser in-built Open/Save file dialog because your answer will require repeating the code behind these in-built Open/Save file dialog.